# Visual Studio 2012 failing to detect Visual Studio 2008 build tools

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, c++-cli, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2012 to build a C++ CLI application targeting .NET 3.5.

I've already gotten this working on one machine, by installing Visual Studio 2008, and specifying the v90 platform toolset.

Now I am attempting this on a new machine, and I've installed Visual Studio 2008, then Visual Studio 2012.

Now I get this incredibly frustrating error:

> Error 81  error MSB8020: The builds tools for Visual Studio 2008
>   (Platform Toolset = 'v90') cannot be found. To build using the v90
>   build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the
>   solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install Visual
>   Studio 2008 to build using the Visual Studio 2008 build
>   tools.    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets  43  5   WinApiWrapper
>   (Visual Studio 2008)

Why WOULDN'T Visual Studio 2012 be able to find Visual Studio 2008. Is there any way I can help it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It turns out that you ALSO have to install Visual Studio *2010*.

Once I installed Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2012 was able to detect the Visual Studio 2008 build tools.

It seems absolutely crazy, but there you go.

Comment: I have similar problem, it builds using x86 mode, but doesn't build on x64, do you know (remember) what else needs to be installed?

Comment: @ST3 if you're using Visual C++ x64 you could add 'X64 compilers and Tools' under Visual C++ on 2010 installation

Comment: This was also the key to getting VS2015 to build an old project with VS2008.  Had to install VS2010 for some odd reason.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225637/visual-studio-2012-failing-to-detect-visual-studio-2008-build-tools/57156824#57156824) to learn this "odd reason".

Answer (score 16):

I ran into the exact same problem but I Installed [Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442) instead (or [the web installer version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)) and that made it work also.

I remember I've installed it also to the original computer.

Remember you should uninstall first any version of Visual C++ 2010 redistributable, otherwise [Windows SDK setup will fail](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2717426?wa=wsignin1.0).

I know it's not the perfect solution because Windows SDK is huge, but it's another option.

Comment: This saved me from having to add an express version of VS that I would never use but know would get in the way somehow.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out that VC++2010 redistributable is causing the installer to fail. That seems like a huge cock-up on Microsoft's part, but really is that even anything new?

Comment: In the x86 ISO, setup failed on an x64 system with something to the effect of "cannot find WinSDK_amd64". The x64 ISO version worked but only installed toolchain files for x64.

Answer (score 1):

Before downloading anything try going to project properties -> configuration properties -> general then change the **platform Toolset** for the project to **Visual Studio 2012 (v110)**

Comment: Amazing , smart and simple !

Answer (score 1):

As per [The build tools for Visual Studio 2008 (Platform Toolset = 'v90') cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626642/the-build-tools-for-visual-studio-2008-platform-toolset-v90-cannot-be-foun),

**In addition to an MSVC 9.0 toolchain** which is present in VS 2008 <sub>(do install VS 2008 SP1, or x64 compilers will be broken)</sub>, **you also need MsBuild 4.0 toolset configuration files for this toolchain** so that MsBuild can find it.

**They are discreetly present in Visual Studio 2010,** in the C++ x86 and x64 features, in addition to its own toolchain. **They are also present in WinSDK 7.1 but its installer is broken** on an x64 system; **you can install just the toolset files though** by running `<GRMSDK_EN_DVD.iso>\Setup\vc_stdx86\vc_stdx86.msi` directly (despite the name, it has toolset files for all 3 platforms).