# Platform toolset (v90) not found

Tags: build, visual-studio-2022

I have visual studio sulution with many c++ and c# project.Building on x64 platform suddenly  stopped. But i still can build on x32l. What can be the problem ?
The error:
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(440,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2008 (Platform Toolset = 'v90') cannot be found. To build using the v90 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2008 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".`

Same error occurs when im trying to build 2010 project too (v100)

I tried to uninstall/install VS 2008 nothing changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626642/the-build-tools-for-visual-studio-2008-platform-toolset-v90-cannot-be-foun

Comment: @TimothyG. No, it should work without any upgrade like before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was missing this file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.props
```